# Configure .yml to execute multiple commands

Tags: docker, yaml, configure, circleci

Hello i have simple configuration in my project:

```
version: 2
jobs:
    build:
        docker:
            - image: circleci/node:7
        steps:
            - checkout
            - run:
                name: install-dependencies
                command: npm install
            - run:
                name: tests
                command: npm test
            - deploy:
                name: digital-ocean
                command: ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" user@hostname "cd ~/profile-store; git pull; npm install; forever start app.js"
```

The problem is it need multiply command:

- cd client
- npm start
- cd ..

(in second iteration should install packages from server and in the next run unit tests in client)

I tried these syntax:

- command: ["cd client", "npm install", "cd .."]

But getting an error. The question is :

**How can i write to execute 3 commands in one command instruction?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
command: cd client && npm install && cd ..
```

For enhanced readability, you can use a folded block scalar (folds linebreaks into spaces):

```
command: >-
  cd client &&
  npm install &&
  cd ..
```

Note that you do not really need the final `cd ..` since the shell instance executing the command is not re-used.